# Is using same modules in different files efficient?

Tags: rust, memory-management

Let's say I have two files:

file1.rs
file2.rs

In file1.rs I use module:

`use abc;`

Similarly in file2.rs I use module:

`use abc;`

Is it memory efficient or time efficient to do that? Or should I merge code of file2.rs into file1.rs? to save import time/memory? I want to follow above approach to make my code more readable and manageable.

Comment: What do you mean by "save import time/memory"? Importing doesn't introduce any runtime performance/memory hit. Are you worried about compilation time?

Comment: @freakish, yes compilation time also and memory wise also, will it load that module again in memory or use the already loaded module? just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand. Rust isn't an interpreted language. It is a compiled language.

That means, there is absolutely zero overhead in importing as many things as you want. It will slow down the compiler that creates your program (although even that will only get noticable if you import hundrets of things). But your final executable has no notion of `.rs` files any more, it's all a big bunch of binary, optimized processor instructions.

You can `use` a file 1000 times in different modules, it will most likely still result in only one single instance in the final executable. (or multiple, in the case of generics, but the amount of `use` statements still doesn't matter)

To demonstrate: You can compile your program and then delete all the source files. It will still run.

Comment: It will slow down compilation consideredebly unless caching (of previously imported modules) is performed. For example C and C++ are infamously known for their extremely long compilation times, even without thousands of "imports" (includes). This is due to the design. For example last time I compiled LLVM it took me almost an hour (well, it was few years ago).

Comment: This is a `Rust` question, so I don't think it's fair to compare it with `C`/`C++`. The header/source architecture was great once, but is horribly outdated nowadays. (disclaimer: this is an opinion)

Comment: My point is that you claim that Rust doesn't have this kind of issues. Which would be nice to backup by some reference. Cause I'm not so sure it can handle well thousands of imports. In fact I've seen articles claiming the opposite.

Comment: @freakish Well I don't think it's that simple. If you create a mod with a single function, I claim you can link thousands. If you `use` a mod with a large amount of generics and use them all, of course it will struggle. I think there is no general answer to that. I removed the `thousands` if it makes you uncomfortable.

Comment: @freakish Rust's `use` statements do not conceptually "copy-and-paste" like in C and C++. Rust uses a different compilation model, the *"caching of previously imported modules"* is just the nature of its design. The compilation unit is the *crate* which can be a very large collection of files, so it doesn't really matter what file-organization is used within the crate; it will all be compiled (expanded, resolved, type-checked) as a whole. There's only one stage (AFAIK) that considers files individually which would be during lexing and parsing.

Comment: This is actually _slower_ by default than C/++ (without incremental compilation) because crates tend to be bigger than header files, but yes, importing modules does not affect this.